# How to create a Post by Email system?

Tags: php, email

Like Wordpress and Blogger have. For example, I send an email to something_blog_post@myblog.com and the email that I sent would be transformed in a post on my blog.

Comment: Set up an email account, write a script that will read messages sent to that account.

Comment: Can you give me some tutorial about how to setup an email account without having a full server? Just a simple email that can only receive emails but don't need password and nothing to be accessed?

Comment: There's no such thing as an email account without a password. The best you can do is a blank password, but this is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: If you have control of your own email server, you could configure the delivery to be to a script instead of stored in an account. Some email servers allow this kind of configuration. But you are going to have to something about spam filtering.

Comment: If you like living on the edge, juggling burning chainsaws and all that, you can try creating a `.forward` file that pipes to a script. Remember that you often have one and only one shot to get this right, so if your script crashes, you lose the email permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are services like [mailgun](http://mailgun.com/) that make this fairly easy to do since they convert inbound email into API calls.

The alternative is to find a way to poll IMAP with PHP, then parse the messages. This is probably a whole lot harder.

Comment: Thanks y'all. I'll try Mailgun now, it seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this problem:

1. Firstly, you can setup a system to poll an existing IMAP or POP3 system and return the result.
2. You can setup an email server which will call a script itself upon receiving an email.
3. You can use a third party provider (such as [CloudMailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com) or MailGun).

I wrote a [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/) a little while back outlining some of these options for Rails applications but they all apply directly to PHP too.